# Solve first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE to solve:

$$
xy' + y = -x^2y^3.
$$

Can anyone suggest me the way how to solve it?

Comment: Isn't this standard Bernoulli equation?

Comment: Indeed: use $ \ u = y^{-2} \ , \ du = (-2)·y^{-3} dy \ $ which will transform the equation to $$ x · \frac{dy}{dx} · \frac{du}{dy} \ + \ y ·  (-2)·y^{-3} \ = \ -x^2 · y^3 ·  (-2)·y^{-3} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \frac{du}{dx} \ + \ -2·y^{-2} \ = \ 2x^2 $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ x \frac{du}{dx} \ - \ 2u \ = \ 2x^2 \ \ , $$ for which you can find an integrating factor.

Comment: Thank you guys!

Comment: Or you can combine to $(xy)'=-\dfrac{(xy)^3}{x}$, which is separable.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, this is a Bernoulli differential equation and can be transformed into an easily solvable ODE by dividing everything by $y^3$. This gives
$$\begin{align} 
\frac{x}{y^{3}}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{1}{y^{2}} & =-x^{2}\\
\text{Let $u=\frac{1}{y^2}$}\\
-\frac{1}{2}x\frac{du}{dx}+u & =-x^{2}\\
\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{2}{x^{3}}u & =2x\\
\text{Multiplying by integrating factor $\frac{1}{x^2}$ gives}\\
\int\frac{d}{dx}\left(u\ \frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)dx=\int\frac{2}{x}dx\\
\end{align}$$
The rest is integration.

Answer (score 0):

As @Lutz Lehmann, also points out in the comments , the exact form seems more obvious, (At least to me)

We can work as follows:

$$x\,\frac{dy}{dx}+y =-x^2 y^3 \\
xdy +ydx=-(x^2 \,y^3)dx \\
\frac{d(xy)}{(xy)^3}=-\frac{dx}{x}\\$$
On integration
$$\frac{1}{2x^2 y^2}=\ln(cx)$$
That is it